# Comparing almost equal Counters

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using (abusing) `collections.Counter` to hold non-negative floats. Something like `Counter(a=4.5, b=3.4)`. The problem I faced is that in some case, when comparing two counters, I ran into accuracy issues. Thus, I needed to use something like [`unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual). However, `abs` is not supported for `Counter`'s. So, I wrote the following utility:

```
def assert_almost_equal_counters(c1,c2):
    testcase = unittest.TestCase()
    testcase.assertEqual(type(c1), type(c2))
    testcase.assertEqual(c1.keys(), c2.keys())
    for key in c1.keys():
        testcase.assertAlmostEqual(c1[key], c2[key])
```

Is it enough? Did I miss something?

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: Seems to be the case. I am worried that `unittest.TestCase().assertEqual()` does further tests that I missed.

Comment: Why don't you use a normal `dict` instead of a `Counter`? A `Counter` does not prevent stuff like `Counter(a=-4.5)`.

Comment: I am abusing `Counter` and doing stuff like `Counter(a=3.4, b=2.1) + Counter(a=1.2, c=4.4)`. In any case, counter doesn't handle negative values very nicely. So, for example, `c1 = Counter(a=-4)` is OK. `c1 + Counter(a=10)` yields `Counter({'a': 6})` as expected. However, `c1 + Counter(a=-1)` yields `Counter()`. Luckily, for my use case everything is positive.